# Composite Shared Keys and Entity

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

### I'm working on a database where tables have composite keys and part of that key is shared between tables. I don't know how to set the relationship properly in entity.

Imagine the following:

```
public class Sale
{
        public long ID { get; set; } //Key
        public long RetailerID { get; set; } //Key
        public virtual Location Location { get; set; } //Foreign, Many-to-One
}
```

```
public class Location
{
        public long ID { get; set; } //Key
        public long RetailerID { get; set; } //Key
        public virtual IEnumerable<Sale> Sales { get; set; } //Relationship, One-to-Many
}
```

Both are using the fluent API to define the composite keys `OnModelCreating`.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Sale>().HasKey(x => new { x.RetailerID, x.ID });
modelBuilder.Entity<Location>().HasKey(x => new { x.RetailerID, x.ID });
```

However I am unsure how to finish this to set up the proper relationship as it sets itself up as having duplicate columns for RetailerID which is unnecessary. How is this supposed to be done properly (if at all?)

Comment: Please include the `Key` fluent configuration for the shown entities (in order to see the order of the composite keys).

Comment: The keys as they are have been added.

Comment: To have a one-to-many relationship with composite keys the "many" side typically has a composite key that includes one extra column.  You have identical key columns in the two tables which would indicate a one-to-one relationship.

Comment: Entity defaults a virtual field without IEnumerable to add in something like "LocationID".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible in several ways, all including additional `LocationID` FK property (either explicit or [shadow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties)).

- With shadow FK property (without modifying the entity model):

*Data Annotations:*

```
[Required]
[ForeignKey("RetailerID, LocationID")]
public virtual Location Location { get; set; } //Foreign, Many-to-One
```

*Fluent API:*

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Sale>()
    .HasOne(e => e.Location)
    .WithMany(e => e.Sales)
    .HasForeignKey("RetailerID", "LocationID")
    .IsRequired();
```

- with explicit FK property

*Model:*

```
public long LocationID { get; set; } // added
public virtual Location Location { get; set; } //Foreign, Many-to-One
```

*Data annotations:*

```
[ForeignKey("RetailerID, LocationID")]
public virtual Location Location { get; set; } //Foreign, Many-to-One
```

*Fluent API:*

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Sale>()
    .HasOne(e => e.Location)
    .WithMany(e => e.Sales)
    .HasForeignKey(e => new { e.RetailerID, e.LocationID });
```

(note: use either data annotations or fluent API - no need for both)

Comment: Working on trying to implement this, had to be explicit to get it to pass the create script stage. Will be back if anything happens.

Comment: Sofar as intended. Thank you.